# How to look up what deep links does an app support

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application, ios-universal-links, deeplink

DeepLink/AppLink/UniversalLink are ways for iOS/Android apps to use a url like pointer to jump to a certain location within the app. I'm trying to use that to jump from my app to Google Pay, but I wasn't able to find what are the supported deeplinks from Google Pay. Does any one know how to look up deeplinks an app supports, especially when the app is not open source as for open source apps, look at the `yml` file should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way should be checking the official documentation for integrating with your target app (Google Pay). In your case you should check how Google recommends to start their activities.

A workaround can be to download the APK ([APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/)) and from the Android Studio select `Build \ Analyze APK...`.

Then you can check all supported deeplinks on the `AndroidManifest.xml`, **but** if Google don't want to expose their deep links to other apps then you won't be able to start their app.

Example from v2.106.x:

```
<activity
    android:theme="@ref/0x7f1302d1"
    android:name="com.google.commerce.tapandpay.android.deeplink.DeepLinkActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="2">

    <intent-filter
        android:autoVerify="true">

        <action
            android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="www.android.com"
            android:path="/payapp" />
```

**Important:** Even if you have the scheme://host/path you still have to know which query params (if any) they're expecting in order to work. Again, you should honor the official docs.

Hope it helps!